# What is the difference between "por siempre" and "para siempre" to say "forever"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, sinónimos, vocabulario

I have seen "forever" translated as both *por siempre* and *para siempre*. What is the difference? Are there contexts where you must use one or the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Spain, *para siempre* is the most common form in everyday speech. The form *por siempre* is understood but used only in written or literary/poetic contexts.

Comment: +1 In Argentina it's also like this.

Answer (score 9):

I found an interesting article about the use of `por` and `para`. It's in Spanish and you can find it [here](http://www.pyc-revista.com/numAnt/num4/15_gramatica.pdf).

Quoting the use of `por` and `para` when you talk about time:

> También encontramos las dos preposiciones para señalar el tiempo en el
>   que transcurre o va a transcurrir una acción:
>
> - El artículo tiene que estar listo **para** el jueves.
> - Siempre vuelve a casa **por** Navidad.
>
> Cuando utilizamos la preposición *para* nos referimos a un tiempo
>   exacto, mientras que la utilización de la preposición *por* indica un
>   tiempo aproximado.
>
> En el primer caso el artículo no debe exceder el jueves, que es la
>   fecha límite. Mientras que en el segundo la persona llega a casa en la
>   época de Navidad, pero no se especifica el día determinado en el que
>   llega.
>
> En resumen:
>
> *Por* indica tiempo aproximado / *Para* indica tiempo exacto

So according to the last line you use `por` for **approximate time** and `para` for **exact time**. We are mortals right? So `Forever` usually means `until I die`.

Interestingly enough, people don´t normally know when they're going to die, so the definition of `forever` as an **approximate time** or **exact time** is not so precise.

In my opinion you should use `por` or `para` according to your religious / philosophical / whatever beliefs.

Answer (score -1):

- *Para siempre* = Always (used in common speech).
- *Por siempre* = Forever (used in poetic contexts).