# Is "Nuestro amor arde para siempre" a proper sentence?

Tags: traducción, gramática

My girlfriend is from Mexico and I'm from the States. I have a very limited Spanish vocabulary, an I'm getting her a gift for our anniversary.

It will be a lighter with the phrase "Nuestro amor arde para siempre" engraved on it. Yes, I am aware that this is corny ;)

I just want to know if that phrase is both grammatically correct, and carries the same meaning as the English phrase, "Our love burns forever".

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try sent her the same message in English? She has some level of English language?. A option could be _Nuestro amor durará para siempre_.

Comment: Yes she is fluent in English, but I am learning Spanish and would like to give this to her in Spanish. Also, I would like to use the phrase "burns forever" instead of "lasts forever".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am spanish and I should use:

"Nuestro amor arderá eternamente" or "Nuestro amor arderá para/por siempre".

Using "arde" instead of "arderá" is really strange for me. It sounds really bad.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2):

"Arde" is the absolutely right verb form for "burns" (and I assume that you want to stick with "burns" and not "will burn" [*arderá*] or other verb forms). Your sentence is grammatically correct.

I would favor (and might be a personal preference) a translation like:

> Nuestro amor arde **eternamente**

But "para siempre" is OK. You could even go with ["por siempre"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1865/5481):

> Nuestro amor arde para siempre
>
> Nuestro amor arde **por** siempre

I don't know if there's a regional preference in Mexico between "para siempre" and "por siempre", but it wouldn't be a huge difference. Your proposal ("Nuestro amor arde **para** siempre") is perfectly OK if you want to go with it. It would be a completely personal preference to judge the poetic value of *eternamente*, *para siempre* and *por siempre*. I just offered those you want other options to consider.

Comment: Great, thanks for the extra options as well!